How to extract the value of a "MaskedTensor" while maintaining the gradient?
I have a MaskedTensor (see doc)
print(result)
>>>
MaskedTensor(
  [
    [  1.7866,   2.5468,   1.6330],
    [  2.2041,   2.5388,   2.3315]
  ]
)

I'm trying to calculate a loss with this tensor
loss = 5 - torch.sum(result_summed)

But I'm getting TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'MaskedTensor'
The issue seems to be that even if I call torch.sum(result_summed) I get a 'MaskedTensor' object:
print(torch.sum(result_summed))
>>>
MaskedTensor( 13.0409, True)

How can I extract the value (13.0409 here) to calculate the loss while maintaining the gradient?
